# Get latest content from websites in android app

Tags: android

I want to get the content to be displayed in my android application as soon as it is updated on a particular website.
how can I do that? I'm new to android development....please help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can use  WebView for this purpose please have alook as the example is given below

**res/layout/main.xml –**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<WebView  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/webView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
/>
```

the  **WebViewActivity.java** is as follows

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.webkit.WebView;

public class WebViewActivity extends Activity {

    private WebView webView;

    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.webview);

        webView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        webView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        webView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");

    }

}
```

do not forget to have permission at manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: thanks...can you suggest me a book or something to learn android?

Answer (score 1):

sure use WebView - Android documentation here: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html

You can also consider using PhoneGap and make a hybrid native html5 app.

Answer (score 0):

You can display the web content using these ways,

1. Through cross platforms, such as **[PhoneGap](http://phonegap.com/)** with [jQuery Mobile](http://demos.jquerymobile.com/1.4.2/) or [Sencha touch](http://www.sencha.com/learn/touch) etc,.
2. Through Android **[WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)** class.

If you try to display a web content using Android WebView class, refer this [sample tutorial](http://javatechig.com/android/android-webview-example).